# passing DCPU_DISPATCH option to theano (disabling dispatched CPU optimization)

Tags: cmake, anaconda, mingw, theano

I'm using theano with anaconda on windows.

I faced "Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm\r."

From some search, I found out my current problem comes from the dispatched CPU optimization when theano tries to build the code with GCC (I'm using minGW)

Disabling Dispatched CPU optimizations by passing the -DCPU_DISPATCH= flag to CMake would solve the problem.

I'm looking at conda-build and conda-forge, but it is very hard to figure out how to pass the option.

Could you please advise me of how to pass the build option?

Thank you.